# Web hosting for Israeli visitors

Tags: web-hosting, cdn

I developed a version of a client's main website in Hebrew. Most of the Hebrew site visitors will be coming from Israel. My server is fast in the States but sluggish in Israel (per some ping testing).

How can I speed up serving the site to Israel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find a web host nearer to Israel; it will decrease the ping time and therefore page load time will go down too.

For a more complex solution, you could serve from the US server to people in the US, and anywhere in Europe, you could serve from the other server. [(more info)](http://www.zerigo.com/news/launch-of-geodns-geolocation-load-balancing)

Comment: The DNS solution would be interested, but I think you're right: an Israeli web host is the way to go. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I believe if your target market is Israel, then you need to find the provider on Israel. If you cant find reliable hosting on Israel, you need to find Europe server near your location. Good luck for your job. :)

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question; the answer in 2019 is to use a distributed content delivery network. There are several contenders, though the favorite for many small web sites is CloudFlare because they have a free tier which should work fine at least until you have a better understanding of whether this is sufficient for your requirements.

Any CDN will cache your static content on servers close to the clients, and take care of passing through any dynamic requests to your origin server. A nice bonus with CloudFlare is that they have DDoS mitigation and easy support for Let's Encrypt.

Answer (score -1):

One option which is certainly more complicated is to duplicate the website and put it on two servers, It won't really help with ping time IMO because all request will first have to reach your server which will then
 redirect them to the Israeli server.
(I assume you don't want two separate domains for the landing page)

This can be done with a 301 redirect to another subdomain for example so the browser will cache the subdomain after the first visit so on the second visit the redirects will already be cached and occur automatically

**EDIT:** *according to comment here it's possible to have two DNS servers for one website, I've not done that but if you decide to host on two servers this will certainly help. If you do this the 301 will not need to occur as well saving more time*

The big problem with this approach is if the website has a database and you need to keep a synchronized database between the two servers.

If this is not a problem or you don't mind doing this than the first approach can be good.

Another option which can be regardless of the previous (you can do either one or even both) is to use a caching service / CDN, 
there are some free ones and some paid ones.

This just makes everything faster for everyone and is always good to try when having latency issues.

Good luck!

Comment: `won't really help with ping time IMO because all request will first have to reach your server which will then redirect them to the Israeli server. (I assume you don't want two separate domains)` This is not true. This is done on the DNS level. You can have one server hosting 100 domains or 100 servers hosting one domain. In this case, two servers will be run under one domain, and depending on where the visitor is, they will be directed (not redirected) to the appropriate server.

Comment: okay didnt know about this, I edited, is the redirection of the user to the nearest server done automatically by the root nameservers?

Comment: It's done by just the name servers that your domain itself points to. (In your domain registrar's control panel). You would just move your DNS records to a new host that supports this, and then create various rules (all visitors in Europe use IP `111.222.333.444` and all other visitors use the other IP).

Comment: I could use something like GeoDNS and mirror the site, but I think @ionFish is right. The more efficient solution is an Israeli web host. Great thought experiment, though. I would be really interested in working on this if the site was going to be used more regularly by US visitors, but I think most of the traffic will be from Israel.

Comment: This is just more confused now. The *number* of DNS servers is completely beside the point (you should always have at least two) but they can be configured to return a different IP address to clients in different regions when they ask for the web server. You still need to sync the contents of the two web servers somehow; a common arrangement is for one of them to run a reverse proxy, and defer to the master server for any dynamic conent, as well as content the proxy has not served before.